# How to retrieve a value in Realtime Database using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I don´t have a lot of programming experience, and I´m trying to solve the following:
Given this data structure using Realtime Database
[Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A68c.png)
I want to show in an HTML table the value of the `"propina"` key, but not the identifier that the Realtime Database generates.

Up until now, I´m running this code to retrieve the values of the data:

`

```
    var database = firebase.database();     

    database.ref().once('value', function(snapshot){

         if(snapshot.exists()){

             var content = '';

             snapshot.forEach(function(data){

                 var val = data.val();

                 content +='<tr>';

                 content += '<td>' + val.nombre + '</td>';

                 content += '<td>' + val.lugar + '</td>';

                 content += '<td>' + val.ubicacion + '</td>';

                 content += '<td>' + val.propina + '</td>';

                 content += '</tr>';

             });

             $('#ex-table').append(content);

         }

     });`
```

But the "`propina"` value is not displayed, giving me just `\[object Object\]` in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `propina` is an *object*, not a *string* or a *number*.
You need to access its **value**. You can access the value like this:

```
  ...

  content += '<td>' + val.propina.value + '</td>';

  ...
```